# Conditional Expectation of Integral over square of Brownian Motion - PDE Approach

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, heat-equation

I am looking to compute the following using Ito's formula.

$$u(t,\beta_t) = \mathbb{E}(\int_t^T\beta_s^2ds|\beta_t)$$

Knowing the properties of brownian motion, it is rather easy to show that the above is equivalent to $\frac{1}{2}(T^2-t^2)$; however, i'm looking to apply Ito's formula to come up with a similar result. Given that $u$ is a martingale, it follows from Ito's formula that $u$ satisfies the homogenous heat equation:

$$u_t = -\frac{1}{2}u_{xx}$$ Though I am struggling to see how the solution aligns with what I found using the easier approach.

Side note:

My boundary conditions: $$u(T,x) = 0$$ $$u(0,0) = \mathbb{E}(\int_0^Tds) = T $$
Though I could be off here, as the expectation is confusing me

Edit:

My approach to finding $\frac{1}{2}(T^2-t^2)$ through knowledge of B.M.:

(1) By the tower property, using the fact that $\beta_t\in F_t$
$$u(t, \beta_t) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\int_t^T\beta_s^2ds|F_t)|\beta_t)$$

(2)Then given the integral is not within $F_t$, we have
$$u(t,\beta_t) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\int_t^T\beta_s^2ds)|\beta_t)$$

(3)

$$u(t,\beta_t) = \mathbb{E}((\int_t^T\mathbb{E}(\beta_s^2)ds|\beta_t)$$

(4) Lastly,

$$u(t,\beta_t) = \mathbb{E}(T-t|\beta_t) = \frac{1}{2}(T^2-t^2)$$

Comment: Your conditional expectation is not conventional mathematical notation. Either you stick to that or you need to explain what you mean. If I intepret it in the most reasonable way, i.e. you condintion your integral on the natural filtration of $\beta$ till time t, than this will not be equal to $T-t$ but rather $1/2 (T^{2}-t^{2})$.

Comment: I'm working from the following corollary: Let $X_t$ be a Markov process and $F_t$ be the natural filtration associated with this process. Then according to the above lemma for any function V process $\mathbb{E}(V(X_T)|F_t)$ is a martingale and applying Markov property we get that $\mathbb{E}(V(X_T )|X_t)$ is a martingale. In the following we often write $\mathbb{E}(V(X_T)|X_t)$ as $\mathbb{E}_{X_t=x}V(X_T)$ .@Tobsn Not sure if this helps clarify what i'm working from -> the expectation is conditioned on a path (subset of filtration from my understanding)

Comment: @Tobsn Please see edit for explanation

Comment: The $u(t,\beta_t)$ function you describe is not a martingale because the random variable inside the conditional expectation changes with $t$.

Comment: I don't think what you are saying is true - $\beta_t$ (Brownian Motion) is a Markov Process @user6247850

Comment: What does $\beta_t$ being a Markov process have to do with whether or not $u(t,\beta_t)$ is a martingale?  Those are completely independent properties.

Comment: Function $\frac{1}{2}(T^2-t^2)$ doesn't satisfy the heat equation $u_t = \frac{1}{2}u_{xx}$.

Comment: @Andrew true, but if u is a martingale then $du = u_tdt + u_xd\beta_t + \frac{1}{2}u_{xx}dt$ implies that $u$ should satisfy which is where i'm confused here

Answer (score 1):

Before going into the details of my solution, I'd like to point out how the first comment was right: your computations are wrong and indeed that expectation is $1/2(T^2-t^2)$. We can see it this way:

$$
\mathbb{E}[I] = \int_{t}^{T}\mathbb{E}[W_{s}^{2}] ds = \int_{t}^{T}s ds = \frac{1}{2}(T^2 - t^2)
$$

I'm not sure whether by "using Ito" you meant to do what I'm about to, but here's what I did.

Let consider the function $f(t,W_t) = tW_{t}^{2}$ and apply Ito:

$$
TW_{T}^{2} - tW_{t}^{2} = \int_{t}^{T}(W_{s}^{2} + s) ds + \int_{t}^{T} 2s W_{s}^{2}dW_s = I + \frac{1}{2}(T^2-t^2) + 2\int_{t}^{T}sW_{s}^{2}dW_s
$$

By taking the expectation, and noticing that the stochastic integral vanishes and $\mathbb{E}[W_{s}^{2}] = s$ we have once again the same result as before.

Another function we could have used is $f(W_t)=W_{t}^{4}$

Comment: Ah yes -> Silly mistake on my end will edit now. Thank you